# Sum dynamic amount of vectors

Tags: vhdl

I basically have two vectors (type: integer, signed, unsigned, std_logic_vector, doesn't really matter for the imlementation).

Vector 1 has a static size of 16 (equals 1word).
Vector 2 has a dynamic size of X*16 (equals X words)
X is the dynamic parameter.

Now I want to have a construct where I can sum X words from vector 2 depending on the parameter X.

sth. like this:

```
vector_1 <= for i in 0 to X generate
             vector_2(X*16+15 downto X*16) +
            end generate;
```

Anyone can imagine something like this being possible in VHDL?

Cheers,
Steffen

EDIT: Maybe to make it more clear, what I want to have:

```
accumulated_data <= std_logic_vector( signed(data_vector(0*16+15 downto 0*16)) +
                                      signed(data_vector(1*16+15 downto 1*16)) +
                                      ...                                       
                                      signed(data_vector(X*16+15 downto X*16))  
                                    );
```

X is static at synth.

Comment: Should `X` be able to change during run time? You can't have a synthesisable VHDL construct whose size is dynamic during run time.

Comment: no, X is static at synthesis

Comment: How large could `X` be? Is it feasible to have Vector 2 use block memory resource?

Comment: X,max is about 8. blk_mem is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `data_vector`, I would use a custom type, something like:

```
type WORD_ARRAY_type is array (integer range <>) of signed (15 downto 0);
signal data_vector : WORD_ARRAY_type (2 downto 0);
```

Your sum is then more readable, something like:

```
vector1 <= data_vector (0) + data_vector (1) + data_vector (2);
```

The single-cycle code would be something like this:

```
process (clk)
    variable sum : signed (vector1'range) := to_signed(0, vector1'length);
begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        sum := to_signed(0, vector1'length);
        for i in 0 to (data_vector'length - 1) loop
            sum := sum + data_vector(i);
        end loop;
        vector1 <= sum;
    end if;
end process;
```

Although it is up to the tools to interpret this as a single cycle multi-input sum, which they may not.

However, an adder with 8 inputs is going to be very slow. My approach would be something like this:

- A counter set to stop once it reaches `X`.
- An accumulator fed by a variable size multiplexer.
- Multiplexer inputs connected to Vector 1 and Vector 2, controlled by the counter.
- State machine or similar to control the accumulator, based on the count (i.e. stop adding once `X` is reached).

Comment: I think you need to replace (vector2'length - 1) in your loop by the parameter (X-1). I like the approach with the custom type. Kudos for that! :)

Comment: based on your question, `vector2'length` will be the same as `X`. If you use attributes then the `X` need not even be a generic in the entity. The custom type is really helpful when the bit width of your data changes.

Comment: If I take my example, vector_2'length would be X*16 resulting in an out of range error for data_vector(i). I believe one can write (vector2'length / vector1'length). Does this make it more clear what I mean? How did you understand my question in that concern?

Comment: my solution assumes that you use the custom type, in which case the length of `data_vector` is the number of words contained within it (i.e. `X`)

Comment: Aaahhh.. ok, I see. Got it. vector2 and data_vector are the same here. sweet, thx for help!

Comment: Ah! ok no that's an error in the code I posted. I edited it to use `data_vector` everywhere, and missed one of the `vector2`s. My mistake!

Comment: Excellent.  Question, is the average synthesis tool good enough to restructure the daisy chain of adders to a binary tree?  A simple fix would be use a function that does recursion.  OTOH, does the average synthesis tool support recursion?

Comment: I think we've had a question recently where something similar to this would not synthesize properly, which is what led me to note that the tool may well not support this. By a recursive function, do you mean something like Morten's answer?

Comment: The `sum` argument must be cleared to 0 before the loop, if sum is only to cover the `data_vector` at each call.

Comment: oh, i thought he wanted to add vector 1 to all of vector 2, not all of vector 2 *into* vector1. Will correct.

Answer (score 1):

A function can be used to do the sum, where X is determined through simple length division:

```
function vector_sum(vec_2 : std_logic_vector; len_1 : natural) return std_logic_vector is
  variable res : std_logic_vector(len_1 - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
  for i in 0 to vec_2'length / len_1 - 1 loop
    res := std_logic_vector(signed(res) + 
                            signed(vec_2((i + 1) * len_1 - 1 + vec_2'right downto 
                                         i * len_1 + vec_2'right)));
  end loop;
  return res;
end function;
```

The function is then used like:

```
vector_1 <= vector_sum(vector_2, vector_1'length);
```

Comment: For my own understanding, is putting essentially the same code into a function any different to having it as part of the 'main' rtl, apart from any reusability benefits?

Comment: The function does not require any `WORD_ARRAY_type` type, and allows concurrent assign to `vector_2`, thus without need of a process.  So using a function taking a `std_logic_vector` argument, is a solution that is closer to the types and code example in the question.

Comment: OK, thanks. I wondered if a function might help the synthesis tool to do the right thing per JimLewis' comment

Answer (score 0):

Solved it as well:

```
process(clk)
    variable TMP : std_logic_vector(accumulated_data'range) := (others => '0');
begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        for i in 0 to X-1 loop
            TMP := std_logic_vector(  signed(TMP) +
                                      signed(data_vector(i*25+24 downto i*25))
                                   );
        end loop;
        accumulated_data <= TMP;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Works the first time, but on the next clock, TMP will retain its value from the previous execution.  Initialization of a variable object only happens when the variable is elaborated.  For a process this happens once at the start of time - in a subprogram (see Morten's solution), it happens each time the function is called.   In your process, rather than initializing TMP in its declaration, you need to do it just after the if rising_edge(Clk) with an explicit variable assignment.